# In chrome extension, how to listen for events for a page that is dynamically generated by the content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have injected an html file in chrome extension using content script. Now I need to listen for events for the elements of that page. So how do I do that? Should I write the code in content script or in a separate javascript file?

Comment: What do you mean under "injected an html file in chrome extension using content script"? An injection makes sense for injecting a script and probably generating custom DOM elements into 3-d party content, not into your own extension.

Comment: The script was already injected, and by the use of that script I brought the contents of another html file and then appended it to current document in browser. Thats what I mean by Injection here.

Comment: OK. What's the problem with binding some events to the elements? As you already have a content script, do it right there.

Comment: Well, the problem is that, I dont know as to under which 'window' event I should listen for my elements? I tried window.onLoad but then fetching my element gives null.

Comment: I don think your problem is not in the binding target (`window` element), but rather in the sequence it's performed. You did not show any code (which would be very helpful for answering your question), but I suspect that you load your content script at default `run_at` moment, which is `document_idle`. Can it be that the idle happens before your external html is loaded? Try using `document_end`, and show your code.

Comment: Content scripts in chrome extensions run in their own separate JavaScript VM, so you can't access script variables in the main window directly. You can only communicate through the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for events in Content Scripts using Mutation Observers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Note that mutation observers watch for changes to the DOM, not to the values of elements. So you can watch a textarea to see if an attribute is added to that element, but you cannot watch that textarea to see if its value changes.